# compress binary data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am **storing images** in my database(Sql Server 2008) **in binary formate**.
Table's Field datatype is image.

Right now i'm having rows above than millions in that table. Now i want to **compress that binary data.**

I have searched some solutions but they are on form levels means i have to write code in C# or VB.net and bring that binary data on that page. By compressing them with code i have to update that particular record.

but due to i have large number of data it is inconvenient to do this process on form side because it can take plenty of time.

So all i want some **code for SQL** so i can **create Stored Procedure** in my database, using which i can get each row at a time,**directly compress that binary data and update** that fetched column for that perticular row.

Is there any method available to do this process on **SQL server 2008**.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: "all i want some code for SQL". That's not how we do things here. You show us why you tried, what didn't work and explain where you are stuck, then we can give you a hand with that.

Comment: all i'm getting is C# codes. So i have to create 1 project in C# so i can get data from server compress them on project side and again save that compressed data on sql.

Comment: I'm not able to find code in SQL right now. I have searched so many things but failed.

Comment: I know that in MySQL (not SQL Server though) there is `compress` function.

Comment: Are you sure the images aren't already compressed anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 Developer or Enterprise Edition, you can enable compression as described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the `FILESTREAM` type in SQL Server, the server should already support compression starting with 2008.

Have a peek at [The MSDN docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28SQL.105%29.aspx) all you would need to do is make sure the file-steam was located on a compressed volume and it would happen on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLR: Here's one already written and ready to roll... http://www.sqlmag.com/article/common-language-runtime-clr/using-large-clr-udts-in-sql-server-2008